# A specific StoryBoard for iOs 7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, ios7

I'd like to optimize my app on iOs7 but this is really hard.
Xcode looks pretty buggy...

Do you know if it is possible to have 2 storyboards, one for iOs7 and the other for older versions ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what you need to do. Put this type of logic in your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your app delegate:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define iOS_7_OR_LATER SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7")

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:iOS_7_OR_LATER ? @"Storyboard-iOS7" : @"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```